# Azure Event Hub Consumer Groups

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I get that consumer groups will retrieve messages from the Event Hubs however;

Assume I have 1 producer, 32 partitions and 2 CG's, CG 1 will use the data in a different source but needs the same message.

Does a message in the queue replicate across all 32 partitions so CG1 & CG2 will retrieve the same sequenced data?

New to this so thanks for any help!

Comment: Feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer below or ask for clarification so it can benefit others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both consumer groups will receive the same data. They both have an independent view of that data. That means that CG1 might be further in processing the messages then CG2. If, for example, CG1 processes message in memory it might be going through the messages faster than CG2 that is doing a lot of I/O to handle the messages. But they will both have access to all the data.

Does this make sense to you?